# JSF related Maven Configuration marker in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, jsf-1.2, facet

I'm developing a **Maven web application** which is composed by two war files, using overlaying method. That war files are using JSF 1.2 dependencies. I have no problem building, deploying or running the project, everything works fine, however I get an error marker which is driving me mad:

[image]

It looks like Eclipse is not noticing about Dynamic Web Module 2.5 in my wars, even I have this facet installed. Now I'm working with Eclipse Juno, but I experienced this problem with previous releases too. Seems that there's some trouble with JSF 1.2 facet. That's my *org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml* file:

**Main project**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.6"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"/>
  <installed facet="jst.jsf" version="1.2"/>
  <installed facet="jst.jaxrs" version="1.0"/>
  <installed facet="jboss.m2" version="1.0"/>
</faceted-project>
```

**War dependency**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <fixed facet="wst.jsdt.web"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="1.6"/>
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"/>
  <installed facet="wst.jsdt.web" version="1.0"/>
  <installed facet="jst.jaxrs" version="1.0"/>
  <installed facet="jboss.m2" version="1.0"/>
  <installed facet="jst.jsf" version="1.2"/>
</faceted-project>
```

Did anybody have similar problem? I think facet configuration is properly done, so don't know why I'm getting this error..

**UPDATE**

It could be a server runtime configuration issue, but if I go to my project's configuration, in **Java Build Path**, *Libraries* tab, everything I find is JRE System Library for JavaSE-1.6 and Maven dependencies attached. It seems not to have a server runtime sticked.

Comment: Are you using the latest m2e and m2e-wtp with JSF configurators?  I know that a recent release addressed many issues.  http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg03820.html

Comment: I made a revert of Eclipse related files to the branch project (to match workmates config) and it seems to work now. Previously I had three options into *Project Facets Java -> Server Faces* submenu, now I have only two and I choose "Disable Library Configuration". Previously I had *User library*, *Disable library Configuration* and a third option related with Maven and JSF (even I also had the same choice selected).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning there indicate that "*some where*" in your project, dynamic web module is set to version less than 2.5

Based on the faces config you provided, it seems you are using DWM 2.5

```
<installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"/>
```

So some where else in your project, there is reference to lower version.

- **Check Your web-app definitions and schemas, web.xml file. It should be web-app_2_5**

---

```
<web-app xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/webapp_2_5.xsd"
 schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
```

---

- **web.XML doc Type**

---

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
```

---

Comment: You definitelly struck home. I had the version of my web.xml set to 2.4. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what is happening is your server runtime, selected in a 
previous page in the wizard, is filtering the web module versions that are 
available based on what its adapter allows.

I am using Tomcat 6 - it works quite well for me and supports version 2.5.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I still can't figure out how to resolve that. If I go to *Properties->Java build path->Libraries*, where the runtime is supossed to be configured, I have not server runtime attached to my project. The same happens in my two war files. I only have Maven dependencies and JRE System Library attached. I update my question with that point, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Xtreme Biker

simple way to change dynamic web module

click right click on project -> properties -> project facets -> click on link then change dynamic web module part as your requirement.

[image]